# Reloading the page after redirect

Tags: javascript

In my application I have a link for logout.

`html`

```
<a onclick="myFunction()">Logout</a>
```

`js`

```
function myFunction() {
    document.location.href = 'https://url/oauth/logout?redirect=https://url';
}
```

The problem I am having is, when I click logout, I immediately redirects to the `url`. It seems like I am not logged out but after I refresh manually, I get logged out.

I also tried `window.reload();` inside `myFunction()` but it actually doesn't get called at all.

Is there a way to reload the page after the `myFunction()` is called.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you are already redirecting someone you dont want to reload a page you just redirected to. What does your  myFunction do? Your logout logic should update the UI properly so once you redirect the UI correctly displays what a logged out user should see.

Comment: @GifCo To make you clear, I don't actually want to reload the page after logout and redirect. I have a api `https://url/oauth/logout` that logout the user and after that I want to redirect to login page. For this I used `redirect=https://url` after logout. But for me I have to manually reload to page to actually make sure it was successfully logged out, that is the reason I wanted to reload the page. Is there any other options that you can share that I can implement. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fetch the logout endpoint and then reload the page if it was successful like so:

```
const myFunction = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const response = await fetch('https://url/oauth/logout');
  if (response.ok) {
    location.replace('new-url');
    // or location.reload()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a "client side" redirect, try a "server side" redirect in whatever language you are using.

```
<?php
    Logout Logic here
    header("Location: /login_url");
?>
```